# Making a partial function complete

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is there a standard way to complete a partial function `PartialFunction[A, B]`? Something like this:

```
completePartialFunction(pf: PartialFunction[A, B], z: B): A => B
```

or

```
completePartialFunction2(pf: PartialFunction[A, B], f: A => B): A => B
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's actually very simple:

```scala
  def complete[A, B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(f: A => B): A => B =
    pf.applyOrElse(_, f)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `lift` method on `PartialFunction`, that returns `Option[B]`. So when the function is not defined for the input, `None` is returned. You can find more in the [scaladocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html#lift:A=%3EOption%5BB%5D).

Other solution that comes to my mind is when you're using [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) or [scalaz](https://scalaz.github.io/7/). You can then check whether the function is defined for the argument and when not, return `empty` from the `Monoid[B]` that you should pass (probably implicitly) to `completePartialFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, you want to use `f()` to supplement `pf()` so that all possible values of type `A` are covered.

```
def completePartialFunction2[A,B](pf : PartialFunction[A,B]
                                 ,f  : A => B): A => B =
  (a:A) => if (pf.isDefinedAt(a)) pf(a) else f(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple version:

```
def completePartialFunction[A, B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B], f: A => B): A => B
  = pf orElse { case a: A => f(a) }
```